# Semigroup without left cancellation law and right cancellation law

Tags: abstract-algebra, semigroups

Can please someone give example of a Semigroup in which neither left cancellation law hold nor right cancellation law

Comment: How about the group of $n\times n$ matrices with multiplication?

Comment: You asked for a semigroup, not a group. This wouldn't make sense in the context of a group anyways since groups satisfy the cancellation laws...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Any nontrivial ring (e.g. integers or reals) with multiplication works (because for any $x,y$ we have $0\cdot x=x\cdot 0=y\cdot 0=0\cdot y$).

Answer (score 0):

A finite commutative monoid of order - e.g. - $4$ that makes the job is

$$\begin{array}{c|cccc}
\ast & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4\\\hline
1 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4\\
2 & 2 & 2 & 3 & 4\\
3 & 3 & 3 & 3 & 4\\
4 & 4 & 4 & 4 & 4\\
\end{array}$$
Here, for example,
$$\color{red}{2}\ast 1=\color{red}{2}\ast 2\quad\text{but}\quad 1\ne 2$$
and
$$1\ast \color{red}{4}=3\ast \color{red}{4}\quad\text{but}\quad 1\ne 3.$$